# Calling SOAP API through proxy with node-soap client

Tags: node.js, soap, soap-client, node-soap

I am using the node-soap module and it's working fine, except when I am working behind a proxy. I can't manage to find the way to set that proxy so I can request the API.

```
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
      client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result) {
          console.log(result);
      });
});
```

It's written in the docs :

```
The options argument allows you to customize the client with the following properties:

request: to override the request module.
httpClient: to provide your own http client that implements request(rurl, data, callback, exheaders, exoptions).
```

Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the `soap.createClient()` options set `'request'` to a request object that has `'proxy'` set using `request.defaults()`.

```
let request = require('request');
let request_with_defaults = request.defaults({'proxy': PROXY_URL, 'timeout': 5000, 'connection': 'keep-alive'});
let soap_client_options = {'request': request_with_defaults};
soap.createClient(WSDL_URL, soap_client_options, function(err, client) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, after looking at the code, I found that you could just declare your proxy as an environment variable.

```
process.env.http_proxy = 'http://proxyhost:proxyport';
```

This works!